# ROWNUM equivalent in Centura SQLBase (aka Gupta)

Tags: query, gupta-sqlbase

I have a Centura SQLBase (version 7, so it is over 10 years old; now apparently they changed the name back to Gupta) where I need to put a running number into a column while copying data into a temporary table.

The running number has to restart when a grouping code changes (so each group has its own counter), the data has to be ordered by a date column.

This is a conversion task. For testing (UAT) I only have to convert parts of the database (though it isn't really big, so I just want to convert all). For go-live, I will do a final conversion and the database will be disabled. So to be exact: it is a two-times task. Though not mission critical any outage is annoying for the users, as they have to switch to papers and then later key-in (instead of immediately key-in)

In essence I have this data:

```
employee_no,date,group_code
```

and I have to generate:

```
employee_no,date,group_code,group_running_number
```

The employee_no + date + group_code is the PK.

In Oracle, I would use an analytic function and get it done in one step, but in SQLBase I even cannot find something like "rownum".

I considered using the `SYSDBSequence.nextval` sequence, but it stayed the same for a single insert (which probably makes sense).

I considered using their `ROWID` (which contains a unique row number and I know how to pick that out), but I cannot use the `ORDER BY` in the `INSERT-SELECT` combo. (When creating views `ORDER BY` isn't allowed either)

One last resort, if I cannot solve this with SQL, would be using a spreadsheet. There are only about 400,000 rows in total, but it certainly would be rather slow and error prone. On the final conversion day I want to have as few steps as possible.

If I cannot find a `rownum` equivalent I might try writing a procedure in sqltalk doing RBAR processing.

Answer (score 3):

One way to emulate row numbers in DBMS that do not have window function is using a triangular self join. It's usually not very efficient though.

Given that the primary key is `(employee_no, date, group_code)`:

```
SELECT
    a.employee_no, a.date, a.group_code,
    COUNT(*) AS group_running_number
FROM
    tableX AS a
  JOIN
    tableX AS b
      ON  a.group_code = b.group_code
      AND ( a.date > b.date
         OR a.date = b.date AND a.employee_no >= b.employee_no
          )
GROUP BY
    a.group_code, a.date, a.employee_no ;
```

The order used for the assigning of row numbers above is: `(date ASC, employee_no ASC)`

An index on `(group_code, date, employee_no)` will improve efficiency I think.

Comment: Silly me, how could I miss that! It does improve runtime _significantly_ although it still uses the INDEX LOOP: the 42,000 rows now took just 6 min.; 86,000 rows took 28 min. (so for the 400,000 rows it probably will still be a bit too slow; but I learned from your comments - thanks a lot!)

Answer (score 3):

I checked the documentation once more and conclude that there is no rownum equivalent in Centura SQLBase (at least not in that old version; they have a version 11.7 now).

So I bit the bullet and wrote a procedure to process the data RBAR-style (Row-By-Agonizing-Row), which turned out not so bad. It took 3 minutes to process the 300,000 rows test data in my local test database.
The procedure isn't saved anywhere, I just ran it in "sqltalk", the SQL client that came with the database. Maybe it can be useful to someone in the future to see how to do that:
(Long lines can be broken up with a backslash, but that messes up the syntax highlighting in here. FYI: I committed manually.)

```
procedure: createRunningNum
Parameters
    receive number: nTotal
    receive string: sMessage
Local Variables
    sql handle: hSql1
    sql handle: hSql2
    Number: nInd
    Number: nCount
    String: sROWID
    String: sGC
    String: sGCold
Actions
    call SqlConnect(hSql1)
    call SqlConnect(hSql2)
    call SqlPrepareAndExecute(hSql1,'select rowid,group_code from TMP_TEST order by group_code,date_ into :sROWID, :sGC ')
    call SqlPrepare(hSql2,'update TMP_TEST set RunningNumber=:nCount where rowid=:sROWID')
!   Note: if we set sGCold to a null-string, the condition "sGCold!=sGC" is always false!
    set sGCold='q#q@q! anything we can be sure not to encounter by chance'
    set nTotal=0
    while SqlFetchNext(hSql1,nInd)
        if sGCold!=sGC
            set nCount=0
            set sGCold=sGC
        set nCount=nCount+1
        call SqlExecute(hSql2)
        set nTotal=nTotal+1
    call SqlDisconnect(hSql1)
    call SqlDisconnect(hSql2)
    set sMessage='rows updated.'
\
42,anything
/
```

To compare my version with ypercube's version I also ordered by employee_no and indeed received an exactly identical result. So I am confident that ypercube's version would theoretically work, it just isn't practical for large sets (but nevertheless a very creative solution given the limited abilities of that database).

The trigger suggestion is another interesting idea, but as I have a fast solution already I doubt I will ever test it.

FYI: Centura-SQLBase (version 7) has only ONE global sequence, and it might jump. I never investigated if it would avoid holes as single user, but I can confirm that it wraps to zero after 2^32 increases.

So I envisioned having an extra table that tracks the maximum running number for each group. I would be the only one inserting into the temporary table, so there would be no concurrency issues. With only about 30 groups I would expect a roughly constant time spent for each insert and no significant degrading processing speed per line as the table grows.
(The conversion would be one single insert into the temporary table with the trigger taking care of the running number.)

I would expect the trigger version to be faster than the self-join above a certain size, but not as fast as the specialized "one-time" function I wrote.

I want to thank both contributors for their creative suggestions.

Comment: Nice. Is that similar to cursors (in SQL-Server)? I run through the Centura SQL pdf and it mentions cursors (available in SQLTalk) but not much details. Perhaps you can try that road, too. (Just run a simple `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY group_code, date, employee_no` through the cursor and let it assign the row numbers)

Comment: I don't know much about SQL server; sqltalk can connect to several databases (each database connection gets a unique number) then you can do e.g. "copy 1.tmp_view to 2.final_table;" but you have to make sure the column order is correct. It is sqltalk that processes the copy. (The procedure I wrote is processed by the database; the docu says about SqlConnect: Connects to the currently active database). But your suggestion is a 3rd possibility namely I copy the data over to an Oracle database and process over there. (sqltalk comes with connection DLLs for Oracle and other databases)